# Wrong tag returned of UITextfield inside UITableviewcell After Row Deletion

Tags: ios, uitableview, tags, uitextfield

I have got a UITextfield in each cell, whom I am assigning a tag equal to current row number.

`cell.textfield.tag = indexPath.row;`

I need **indexpath.row** when user ends editing the textfield.

```cs
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [[textField superview]superview];

if([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){

    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [Table indexPathForCell:cell];

    int row = textField.tag;
    NSLog(@"indexpath: %d",row);

NSString *str = [datasource objectAtIndex:row]; //get exception here
.............. }
```

Problem I am facing here is that when I delete a row using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, and then end editing last cell, I get wrong tag number, because data source does not contains element at that index. Moreover, I cant use `indexPathForCell:` because if my cell whose textfield is being edited goes out of screen, it will return null.

What can I do to get correct tag number? I don't want to reload table as it does not got any animation. What can be alternate? Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing deletion of row in this tag `[tableView BeginUpdates]` & `[tableView endUpdates]` ?

Comment: yes i am doing inside these tags.

Comment: Don't use indexPath.row to assign tag, you can rather defined your values..

Comment: If I assign my own values to tags, how will they be changed when I delete a row?

Comment: I need a correct value to access correct index of array, even when the cell is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use indexPath.row to instead define your value something like below

I have written the code below by assumption, I don't know your datasource that might be different..

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     Data *obj=[[Data alloc] init];
     obj.tag=i;//
     obj.value=@"your value";

     [dataSource addObject:obj];
}

Data *obj=[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textfield.tag = obj.tag;
```

while you will fetch the tag

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [[textField superview]superview];

    if([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){

        //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [Table indexPathForCell:cell];

        int row = textField.tag;
        NSLog(@"indexpath: %d",row);

        Data *obj;
        for(Data *data in dataSource){
            if(data.tag == row){
                obj=data;break;
            }

        }

        NSString *str = obj.value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will tell you later after getting the result.

Comment: If I delete a row, my datasource is updated. How will I manage tag numbers according to it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be much easier to use the free Sensible TableView framework to manage all these text fields. The framework simply creates them based on your class properties and automatically writes back the entered values to your classes. Really easy to use and straightforward for iOS forms in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I am unable to use this control at this stage. I will keep it in mind for future. Thanks:)